# Android - Installed apps - integrity check

Tags: android

1. If someone tampers with an installed android app (apk file), are there any checks done at the time of launching to ensure integrity of an app is not compromised?  As I  understand there are no checks performed at launch time and I am trying to do the following:
2. I am trying to compute SHA-1 digests of the installed applications (apk file).  I am aware that an apk file is like a zip file.  It consists of other files.  However, I am treating it as any other file (just a stream of bytes) and trying to compute SHA-1 digests of all the apk files.  Are there any problems with this approach?  The following code kept on giving null exception:

private static byte[] getSHA1FromFileContent(String filename)
{

```
try
{
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    //byte[] buffer = new byte[65536]; //created at start.
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    int n = 0;
    byte[] buffer = null;
    while (n != -1)
    {
        n = fis.read(buffer);
        if (n > 0)
        {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
    byte[] digestResult = digest.digest();
    return digestResult;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return null;
}
```

}

As an alternative when I attempted to retrieve the files from the apk file and save the individual files as follows, I again kept on null exception

```
public void unzip() 
{ 
        try  
        { 
          FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
          ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
          ZipEntry ze = null; 
          while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) 
          { 
            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

            if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
              _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
            } else { 
                File dstfile = new File(_location + ze.getName()); 
                dstfile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dstfile.getPath()); 
            //OutputStream out = openFileOutput(_location + ze.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
                fout.write(c); 
              } 

              zin.closeEntry(); 
              fout.close(); 
            } 

          } 
          zin.close(); 
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        { 
          Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
        } 
}
```

1. I am also verifying the application configuration by way of - PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences call providing the package name of the application as input parameter
2. In order to verify the integrity of an installed application is the above check enough?

Answer (score 1):

> If someone tampers with an installed android app (apk file), are there any checks done at the time of launching to ensure integrity of an app is not compromised?

There is no such concept as "compromised" from the OS standpoint, other than having an invalid digital signature. If somebody tampers with your app and signs it, that is indistinguishable to the OS from your original app, or the app after Amazon "tampers" with it for their store, etc.

> Are there any problems with this approach? The following code kept on giving null exception

First, you are handling exceptions and doing no logging. You will find that debugging is much simpler when you log your exceptions. Then, you can use the stack trace (e.g., from DDMS) to find the line on which you are crashing, and fix your bug, whatever it is. If you want help with that, you will need to include in your question details on where the `NullPointerException` is occurring.

Second, whoever tampers with your app will simply remove all of this code, if they can find it.

Third, it may be fairly slow, making it easier for them to find it.

> I am also verifying the application configuration by way of - PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences call providing the package name of the application as input parameter

I have no idea why you think that this will be some form of verification.

> In order to verify the integrity of an installed application is the above check enough?

IMHO, the above check is largely useless. If you obfuscate your code (e.g., with ProGuard), call it from several places, and use the other techniques outlined in [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html), perhaps it will be worthwhile, but it may be too slow.

Comment: A device on which a "real" version of an app is installed can however detect an "imposter" upgrade attempt by the change in signature, and respond by wiping out private data files of the original to prevent them from falling into the hands of the imposter.

Comment: Do you have a link to an implementation of your algorithm? I have seen it discussed on occasion but have never seen an implementation. Bear in mind that it won't work for Amazon AppStore or any other markets that re-sign the APK.

Comment: if that was addressed to me, the wipe-on-signature-change is a feature of the android platform itself, that shows up in logcat.  IIRC amazon offers the option of the developer signing the finished apk, though it's not their only option.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Sorry, forgot the @ on that one. Actually, I'm not aware of wipe-on-signature-change, though I am aware of won't-install-on-signature-change. However, that won't help with initial installs.

Comment: the specific code I was looking at doesn't seem to be there in more recent versions. (for some reason the @'s I type are getting stripped out)